# MVC application throws an error "Resource cannot be found"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I created an empty mvc application. Later added a view, a controller and a model for the view. After adding these three parts into the application, i tried running the application. But, i got "resource cannot be found" error from the browser. I cannot figure out the reason behind this.

Is there any settings to be modified to make it run properly? I did not change any settings.

Can anyone help me out of this?

Thanks 
Manikandan

Comment: could you please provide the whole error displayed on the page?

Comment: You should extend your question with the following information: which is the URL what you used in the browser? What is the exact error message? And how is your controller code looks like?

Comment: http://localhost:50295/ This is the url, i tried. And, if i add my controller and action next to that, the result is some error. So, with this, i can understand that there is some problem with my action.

Comment: Actually, i return a JSONresult from my action method to the view.

Comment: Like this, return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = (from student in Student.GetStudentDataList()
                        where student.LastName.StartsWith(name)
                        select student).ToArray<Student>()
            };

Answer (score 0):

Add class config the default route and call it from global.asax
And of course add Home controller with action Index

```
public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you've done is as you described, then the most likely cause for this is that **you've used a Visual Studio template that doesn't include some scripts that are referenced in the auto-generated views** you created.

Try opening the view that has this error (the view that you added) and **remove its `Scripts.Render` directives**, then run your app again and see if it goes away.

If it does go away using the above, then the problem is these missing scripts. In that case, you may either choose not to have them in your app or install them using nuget.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't request the correct url in your browser or you didn't name your controller correctly.

Let's suppose that you wanted to add a HomeController.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC Empty Application
2. Add `~/Controllers/HomeController.cs`

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

   ```
   @{
       Layout = null;
   }

   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Index</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div>

       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. Run the application and navigate to `/Home/Index`

Comment: -I tried the same way as you explained. But, when i press F5, resource cannot be found is shown in the browser. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Where are you hosting your application under? Are you using IIS Express? Or the built in Visual Studio server? Or IIS?

Comment: Built in server of VS.

Comment: Then this should work. Double check that your controller and views are named appropriately.